# Macros opens many files and sporadically crashes

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working with a VBA macro that copies data from large numbers of excel files into a workbook; sometimes over 100 files depending on the user's request. The macro creates new sheets for each file that is copied in.

The function used to copy files is written in this fashion, on a loop:

```
Function ImportOneFile(SimName As String) As Integer

    Dim Temp As Workbook, FileLocation As String, Fld As String, FName As String, ShtName As String

    Fld = SIM_FOLDERNAME:
    FName = OUTPUT_FILENAME

    FileLocation = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Fld & "\" & SimName & "\" & FName

    If Len(Dir(FileLocation)) = 0 Then
        ImportOneFile = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    ShtName = SimName

    '// Prepare worksheet for import
    If Not IsWorksheet(ShtName) Then
        AddSheetAtEnd (ShtName)       'Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = ShtName
    Else
        WipeSheet (ShtName)
        'RemoveChart (ShtName)
    End If

    '// Copy text file into sheet
    Set Temp = Workbooks.Open(FileLocation)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShtName)
        Temp.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy .Cells
        .Columns(1).TextToColumns Destination:=.Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                                                ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Space:=True, TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        .Columns(1).Delete
        If SIMTYPE_KEY = T_SIMTYPE_P Then .Rows(WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(1))).Delete
        Temp.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    ImportOneFile = 1

End Function
```

It operates in a robust fashion when working with smaller numbers of files; less than 30 for example. However, when the function runs with higher numbers of files, it will crash sporadically, generally 1 out of every 5 times, without warning or pattern.

I'm wondering if there is a common reason for this type of problem, whether it has to do with memory issues, or if there are solutions to deal with it.

Comment: you could try saving `ThisWorkbook` between each of your runs

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely to do with memory management.  Excel objects (like workbooks, worksheets, cells etc) are heavy, since they contain not only your data, but also all of this information about formatting etc.

I noticed that you are using the Range.TextToColumns method:

If these are simple text files, then you should consider parsing them using something like the [TextStream Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242724%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).  Make sure you reference the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library (in vba Tools-->References and check "Microsoft Scripting Runtime")

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be that the information imported becomes too big for Excel to manage with available memory, most likely the error is "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources. Choose less data or close other applications.".

One thing you could try to do between each file imported to optimize is save your master workbook, close it and open it again. This way Excel will flush the memory used to transfer the values and much less memory will be occupied when you open again the master workbook.